# Java number subtraction, decompose second number in a sum of 1

Tags: java

I'm making a simple while loop when i can make a subtraction between 2 number in java.
The only task of this exercise is this: 
Suppose that user insert 2 number by this method (

```
Scanner keyboard = number.nextInt();
Scanner keyboard2 = number2.nextInt();
```

Suppose that user insert these 2 number : 8 and 3
I'm not asking for a program which makes 8 - 3 = 5

The program is able to do only substraction or addiction of 1. 
so the five is converted in a substraction of -1 for five time.

So instead of 8 - 3, the program calculate 8 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 = 3

// 8 - 5 
Or :

8 -1 = 7

7 - 1 = 6

// ....

4 - 1 = 3

The exercise don't requires complex method, or for loop, only while

Answer (score 1):

As my point of view, i think that you need your answer like your example. Because of that, i made a program for you. In this program if you only enter large number first, you can except if statement, This is my solution.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Stack2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1=sc.nextInt();
        int num2=sc.nextInt();
        if(num1<num2){
            System.out.println("Number 1 is less than number 2");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int x=num1-num2;
        System.out.print(num1+" - "+num2+" --> is equal to "+ num1+" " );
        while(num1!=x){
            System.out.print("-1 ");
            num1--;
        }
        System.out.println("= "+x);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want like 
8-1=7,
7-1=6,
6-1=5,
// ,
like that you can change code like below
after int x statement

    int y=num1;
    while(num1!=x){
        System.out.println(num1+" -1 = "+(num1-1));
        num1--;
    }
    System.out.println(y+" - "+num2+" = "+x);

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs little correction. You haven't declared Scanner object correct and even numbers. Try this code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num1 = sc.nextInt();
    int num2 = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print(num1 + " - " + num2 + " --> Is equal to " + num1);
    while(num2 > 0) {
        System.out.print(" - 1");
        num1 -= 1;
        num2--;
    }

    System.out.println(" = " + num1);
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: no what is this. i'm not askink tho show -1 like a string.

Comment: im aking for a program that can make addiction or substraction of 1.

Comment: for example 8 - 5 , is not possible to make this substraction because the program is able to do only substraction or addiction with 1, so instead of 8 - 5, the program calculate 8 - 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 = 3

Comment: you understand ?

Comment: oh ok... You actually wanted to subtract the smaller number from larger but by decrementing each time by 1. I have updated my code. Please check if that is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you want some like this

```
    int num1 = 8;
    int num2 = 5;
    int res = num1- num2;
    boolean bandera = Boolean.TRUE;
    String salida = "";


    while(bandera)
    {
        if(num2 > 0)
        {
            salida = salida +"-1";
            num2--;
        }else
        {
            bandera = Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }


    System.out.println(num1 + salida + "=" + res);
```